# When is a @Dependent scoped CDI bean destroyed, if you obtain that bean via Provider.get()?

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi, jboss-weld, weld

I am struggling to understand the effective lifecycle of a `@Dependent` scoped bean in both CDI 1.0 and CDI 1.1. My experiments so far have lead me to the following conclusions:

- A `@Dependent` scoped bean is not proxied.
- No `@PreDestroy` method is invoked when a `@Dependent` bean is destroyed.
- `Provider.get()` always creates a new instance of a `@Dependent` bean.
- With JBoss 6/CDI 1.0, a `@Dependent` bean that is created by an `@ApplicationScoped` bean's `Provider<>` field is "leaked", because it still "belongs" to the `Provider`.
- I have seen no evidence (yet!) of `@Dependent` beans being leaked by similar `Provider`s when using WELD 2.1.2.Final/CDI 1.1. (Although this might be because these *particular* `@Dependent` beans are created by `@Produces` methods...!)

I see that CDI 1.1 has added a `destroy()` method to `Instance<>`, presumably to address the memory leak in CDI 1.0. But what about `Provider<>` - does that still leak in CDI 1.1? (And if it does, then how are you supposed to use `Provider.get()`?)

Basically, I have several `@ApplicationScoped` beans / `@Singleton` EJBs that I `@Inject` `Provider` fields into, and I am trying to use `Provider.get()` as factories for both `@Dependent` and `@RequestScoped` "helper" beans. I definitely do ***not*** want these beans to "belong" to their `Provider` fields, as I need the beans to be garbage collected afterwards:

```
public void updateStuff() {
    Helper helper = helperProvider.get();
    // use helper...
}
```

For my CDI 1.0 application, I was thinking of fixing the memory leak by "faking" my `Provider`s with code like this:

```
provider = new Provider<MyBean>() {
    @Override
    public MyBean get() {
        return getReferenceFor(MyBean.class);
    }
};

private <T> T getReferenceFor(Class<T> type) {
    Bean<?> bean = beanManager.resolve(beanManager.getBeans(type));
    CreationalContext<?> context = beanManager.createCreationalContext(bean);
    try {
        return (T) beanManager.getReference(bean, bean.getBeanClass(), context);
    } finally {
        // Destroy this context - which I don't want to exist anyway.
        // I only need a strong reference to a fully @Inject-ed bean!
        context.release();
    }
}
```

`MyBean` is a `@Dependent` scoped bean with no `@PreDestroy` method that only needs to be garbage collected when I've finished with it. However, I can't find a lot of information about `Provider`s, and so can't tell if I'm arming some kind of time-bomb by doing this.

Some of my `@Dependent` scoped beans (which I still obtain via `Provider.get()`, btw) are created by `@Produces` methods. Are they still in danger of being leaked?

Can anyone advise me, please?
Thanks,
Chris

Comment: I have also had this issue. I verified in JVisualVM that all Dependent beans from my ApplicationScoped bean never get garbage collected because they are dependent on the ApplicationScoped bean. I ended up doing a similar thing as you did. CDI 1.1 fixes this to an extent with the CDI class as Martin said, but I'm on 1.0 in EE6, so I had to use the BeanManager.

Answer (score 3):

From [Weld docs](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/scopescontexts.html#d0e2135) on lifecycle of @Dependent beans:

> An instance of a dependent bean is never shared between different
>   clients or different injection points. It is strictly a dependent
>   object of some other object. It is instantiated when the object it
>   belongs to is created, and destroyed when the object it belongs to is
>   destroyed.

So injection of @Dependent object won't introduce a leak on its own, there's simply nothing to fix. 
Creating a short-lived context just "to be on the safe side" is totally unnecessary because
dependent beans aren't tied to a context. As far as CDI is concerned after being injected they are ordinary (strongly reachable) Java objects.
If you need instantiation logic put it in a [producer method](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/producermethods.html) and that's it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My particular `@Dependent` beans are transient "worker" beans rather than object fields. For example, one of my EJBs has a function that does something like:

    void updateStuff() {
        Helper helper = helperProvider.get();

        // use helper ...
    }

This approach allows the helper to have assorted cDI goodness injected into it, such as an `EntityManager` etc. However, I was unaware that I was leaking the `Helper` object afterwards!

Comment: BTW, according to the [CDI documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/api/1.0-SP1/javax/enterprise/context/Dependent.html):

"An instance of a bean with scope @Dependent obtained by direct invocation of an Instance is a dependent object of the instance of Instance."

So it's slightly more than an "ordinary strongly reachable Java object" - it's bound to its creator! It is this binding that I am trying to undo with my workaround code.

Comment: Simply put that portion of the doc says "No matter how and where you inject it `@Dependent` is a dependent object of the injection point".
So unless an owner of the injection point is leaked it'll be fine.
On the side note, delegating from an EJB bean to a CDI bean is a bit strange; usually it's the other way round.
Wouldn't a stateless EJB be more suitable than a `@dependent` in this case?

Comment: My `Provider` is a field on an `@Singleton` EJB, and so the injection point never goes out of scope. Hence the leak. And I'm delegating from EJB to a CDI bean because a `@Dependent` CDI bean is just a POJO; I only need a light-weight, transient "helper" object. Besides, I've seen _other_ memory leaks with JBoss 6.1.0 and stateless EJBs because JBoss seems to constantly allocate new ones without reusing the old ones unless you configure them with a "strict max pool".

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested your construct, but me personally, whenever I need to go lookup a bean programmatically, I prefer `CDI.current().select().get()`. Using this construct, I can confirm that you will get a new `@Dependent` bean for each lookup. It is not tied to the provider (the CDI container in this case).

See [this](https://github.com/MartinanderssonDotcom/java-ee-concepts/blob/master/src/test/java/com/martinandersson/javaee/cdi/lookup/ProgrammaticLookupTest.java) and [this](https://github.com/MartinanderssonDotcom/java-ee-concepts/blob/master/src/test/java/com/martinandersson/javaee/cdi/lookup/ProgrammaticLookupRunner.java). What we have here is an Arquillian test setup that deploy a Servlet to a "real" (*or "remote" using Arquillian terminology*) server and issues HTTP GET request to find out what beans are produced on the inside.

The outcome is that both GlassFish 4.1 and WildFly 8.2.0 will provide the client code with one new @Dependent bean on each lookup and if I have understood your question correctly, then that is exactly what you want. Hope it helps!

Comment: I had a similar case, using CDI.current().select().get(), but with jprofiler, I still see @dependent instance tied to CreationalContext, and so not destroyed. Any advice?